# Vue.js - v-show and v-for not responding to changes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I would like buttons to show underneath an image in a gallery when the image is clicked. Here is a snippet of my Vue component:

```
<div class="col-xs-2" v-for="(data, key) in imgParsed">
    <a v-show="data != null" href='javascript:void(0);' @click.prevent="showRemove(key)">
        <img :src="data" :alt="key">
    </a>
    <div class="row" v-show="removingImage[key]">
         <div class="col-xs-6">
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger right" value="Remove image" @click.prevent="remove(key)">Remove this image</a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6">
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success left" value="Cancel" @click.prevent="hideRemove(key)">Cancel</a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

1. `removingImage` is an object containing the image name(s) and whether they have been clicked or not.

   Example (in Vue component):

   ```
   ...
   data() {
       return {
           ...
           removingImage: {
               image1: false,
               ...
               imageN: false, // They are all false by default
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. `showRemove(key)` is supposed to show the confirm and cancel buttons when the image is clicked. This is done by setting `removingImage[img]` to `true`.
3. `hideRemove(key)` is supposed to hide the confirm and cancel buttons when the cancel button is pressed. This is done by setting `removing[img]` to `false`

## The problem

When the method `showRemove("image1")`, is called, the value of `removingImage["image1"]` doesn't seem to respond.

**A.** In the Vue Devtools, the value of `removingImage["image1"]` stays false, unless I re-click on my component details, essentially re-evaluating the status of my component.

**B.** In the `showRemove` method, I included the following debugging code:

```
showRemove: function(img) {
    try {
        var a = this.removingImage[img]
        this.removingImage[img] = true; // This was the only thing originally there
        var b = this.removingImage[img]
        console.log('a = '+a,'b = '+b)
        if (a==b && a == false) {console.log('removingImage not updating')}
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Clicking the image once yields `a = false b = true`, and once again gives `a = true b = true`, which tells me that the value of `removingImage["image1"]` *is* updating, but the component isn't 'seeing it'?

**C.** I included some moustaches (or mustaches) within the template like so `{{removeImage[key]}}` so that I could confirm my fears. As I expected, no matter how many times I clicked on the image, it would always show [this](https://mega.nz/#!hoonHYRQ!6AdakBu3OKVaO-r3DvfepV-N75d9DfONb0K2LQutAzY).

Any ideas?

Edit: I will try and reproduce the problem in a fiddle.

Edit(2): The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ouyz2db/3/), as promised (excuse the disgusting code - I am so very new to this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm this is strange. Anyway I got it to work by creating a fresh object and reassigning it ..

```
showRemove: function (img) {
  try {
    var a = this.removingImage[img]
    this.removingImage = { ...this.removingImage, [img]: true }
    var b = this.removingImage[img]
    console.log('a = ' + a, 'b = ' + b)
    if (a == b && a == false) {
      console.log('removingImage not updating')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkfvmogz/)

Or

```
showRemove: function (img) {
  try {
    var a = this.removingImage[img]
    this.removingImage = Object.assign({}, this.removingImage, { [img]: true })
    var b = this.removingImage[img]
    console.log('a = ' + a, 'b = ' + b)
    if (a == b && a == false) {
      console.log('removingImage not updating')
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4reL2mn/)

Alternatively you can use `$forceUpdate` ..

```
showRemove: function (img) {
  try {
    var a = this.removingImage[img]
    Vue.set(this.removingImage, img, true)
    var b = this.removingImage[img]
    console.log('a = ' + a, 'b = ' + b)
    if (a == b && a == false) {
      console.log('removingImage not updating')
    }
    this.$forceUpdate()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ozn9cb8/)

Comment: I don't really know why simple reassignment didn't work, but your first solution worked like a charm. For some odd reason, however, my main project refuses to comply with the `Vue.set()` option. Hmmm...

Comment: The [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats) do recommend using `Vue.set` or creating a fresh object to get around reactivity issues. Quite strange that `Vue.set` doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Vue.set()
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Example:

```
Vue.set(this.removingImage, img, true)
```

Comment: Sorry to say, @edwardbrosens, but it's exactly the same situation... (i.e. nothing has changed. I replaced the `this.removingImage = true` with your suggestion to no visible effect)

Comment: How and where did you replace it?

Comment: I replaced the `this.removingImage = true` with `Vue.set(this.removingImage, img, true)`

Comment: Can you console log the first argument (key) in showRemove when called and  console log 'this' The first argment in showRemove is probably the event and not he actual key. So set key as second argument and $event as first.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I did what you said and logged the value of `key` to the console and I got `image1` as a reply.

Comment: Inside the showRemove method, console.log(img) and console.log(this)
I think the result of img in this case will be an event.