# Select all chekboxes by $emit doesn't re-renders view - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**Case** - Need to select/unselect all checkboxes on change of header checkbox.

**Problem** - I can emit and receive events. Can see my modified data array. But some reactivity isn't working in Vue I guess.

I have laid out very minimal cut out example for same on CodeSandbox - https://88nz9z64j0.codesandbox.io/

**Code** -

https://codesandbox.io/s/88nz9z64j0

**Note** - This has to do something with Array mutation. As I can select individual checkboxes and can see  my header checkbox marked check after all are selected. However, reverse is  just not happening via same mechanism. How Strange!

There has to be a learning from `Array(100).fill(length)` as reactive data else I'm doing something silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Array.fill` was modifying the array in place. Vue [can't detect changes to an array when you directly modify its elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats). You need to create a new array first using `split`, modify the newly created array and then re-assign it.

```
this.checkSelections = this.checkSelections.splice(0).fill(allSelected);
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxj9l1xyj4)

Comment: maybe it is better to use the Vue.set function, no nee to Always create new arrays, with the vue.set you can just modify the elements in a reactive manner in the existing array , less overhead, certainly for large arrays ... see my answer on vue.set

Comment: @Ben I've noticed that `Vue.set` is quite the [hit and miss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52776869/vue-js-v-show-and-v-for-not-responding-to-changes/52778056) affair. Creating fresh arrays/objects seems to guarantee reactivity in all cases. But by all means if `Vue.set` works in a certain case you can definitely use it.

Comment: indeed, but maybe just look at the official information from Vue site: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html, and there is indeed a topic about the 2 approaches on https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats , and in this case i think we do not modify the length of the array, so caveat 1: the vue.set solution, the splice solution is needed when the array changes of length

Comment: Thanks for leading me to docs there. Seems reasonable explanation by you and about mutations. However, as a general practice, I do always create fresh copies as I come from React background. So when it was not working, I had tried this

`      const newArr = Array(this.data.length).fill(allSelected);
       this.checkSelections = newArr;
`

It stil won't work.

Comment: @kushalvm Seems to me that it does work. [See this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yq61k5x55j).

Comment: Second, I did use one of mutative methods - splice and the statement isn't  working for desired results. For example, just select row chekboxes one by one. This will select the header checkbox once all are checked. Now, uncheck the header checkbox. Did you see any update on already checked checkboxes? Isn't happening

Comment: Also see my commented code. I have also tried @BenCroughs suggestion on `Vue.set` and almost other possibilities I could.

Comment: @kushalvm You could try `Vue.set` as @Ben suggested. But my hunch is that this isn't just a reactivity issue and that there's some flaw in the logic.

Comment: Maybe. But actually if you do try to console.log in `selectAll` event receiver, I do see my updated array. For example, if I uncheck the header ( if all other checkboxes are checked), I'll expect my logic to return an array with all false values. Correct? It does that. Do you mind pointing out a flaw? As I said earlier, hope I'm not doing something silly from my end.

Comment: @kushalvm I haven't dug deep into your code to figure that out. My suggestion is to start a new question so that people can look into your code and figure out what's wrong with it. Otherwise they're mostly going to glance over this question and dismiss it as another question regarding reactivity and you won't get much help that way.

Comment: I would like to stick by same question as the question is not about logic I feel. the proof I just discussed. If you are confident, please go ahead and provide that solution. Would be happy to accept it. The motive of SO is to help and not pile more work to gain more points. Isn't it? Taken much effort in sandboxing it already.  Ha-ha!

Comment: @kushalvm I'll see if I can look into it later when I have some time. I'm only  suggesting you start a new question to get better exposure seeing as this one already has three answers and no-one is going to bother with it.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim You were right. I did had to start a new one. Amazed by your observation here of SO of Vuejs tags

 Anyway, mind having a look here ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962268/not-able-to-uncheck-check-chekboxes-on-uncheck-check-of-header-checkbox-after-in

Comment: @kushalvm I'll have a look at it when I get home. For what it's worth I take back my comment about the logic. It could be anything from the way you setup your events to indeed another reactivity issue. Smart move starting that bounty on the question. Lots of smart people here. My guess is that by the time I get to look into it it'll already have been solved. Cheers :)

Comment: Oh no! I want you to catch the bounty 

Answer (score 0):

On your mounted function on table/index.vue you can use this.$forceUpdate() after changing the array, since vue can't see the changes.

```
mounted() {
  this.$root.$on("selectAll", ({ allSelected }) => {
    console.log("selectAll index.vue", allSelected);
    this.checkSelections = this.checkSelections.fill(allSelected);
    console.log("selectAll", this.checkSelections);
    this.$forceUpdate(); 
  });
}
```

You can see more details on [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n940jloky0)

Answer (score 0):

you should check this article about reactivity in vue and it pitfalls https://medium.com/js-dojo/reactivity-in-vue-js-and-its-pitfalls-de07a29c9407, and certain the section on arrays.

For arrays you better make use of the Vue.set

see fork : https://codesandbox.io/s/m7xqk9qn0j

```
 for(var i = 0; i <= this.checkSelections.length; i++)
 {
      Vue.set(this.checkSelections, i , allSelected);
 }
```

detailed information can also be found in on the official vue site:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats
(in this case the length of the array does not change, so caveat1)

Comment: When selecting, all checkboxes, the header checkbox doesn't gets selected in your fork. Plus reassignment in every iteration, wouldn't it be less efficient than re-assigning whole array in one go?