# Not able to uncheck/check chekboxes on uncheck/check of header checkbox after individual checkboxes are interacted with - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**Situation 1** - I check my individual checkboxes, my header checkbox gets checked. This is method 1 and works fine.

Code for same

**index.vue**

```
<VCheckbox
 checked={this.checkSelections[idx]}
    nativeOnChange={e => {

    this.$set(this.checkSelections, idx, e.target.checked);
    let allSelected = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.checkSelections.length; i++) {
        allSelected = this.checkSelections[i];
        if (!allSelected) break;
    }
    this.$root.$emit("checkmarkHead", { allSelected });
    }}
/>
```

**Head.vue**

```
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$root.$on("checkmarkHead", ({ allSelected }) => {
        console.log("checkmarkHead", allSelected);
         this.allSelected = allSelected;
      });
    }

  },
```

**Situation 2 -**

I check my header checkbox and all  my checkboxes are checked. Vice-versa is true as well. So method 2 corresponding to this works fine too.

Code for same -

**Head.vue**

```
  <HeadItem>
    <VCheckbox
        checked={this.allSelected}
        nativeOnChange={e => {
        this.allSelected = e.target.checked;
        this.$root.$emit("selectAll", {
            allSelected: this.allSelected
        });
        }}
    />
</HeadItem>
```

**index.vue**

```
mounted() {
   this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$root.$on("selectAll", ({ allSelected }) => {
        this.checkSelections = Array(this.sortedData.length).fill(allSelected);
     });
   });
 }
```

**Problem -** When I do situation 2 after Situation 1, the same methods don't work as expected. The view isn't updated. Similarly, executing Situation 1 after Situation 2 won't work either.

Here's the link to

Code Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/vmwy3v4203

I'm clueless now after handling all mutations caveats etc.

Comment: Can someone mention the problem with the question downvotes?

Comment: I think it's all the duplicate text you had up there :)

Comment: I noticed, someone has changed the line in mounted function in head.vue in Codesandbox. Very strange! Therefore my use cases as described in question may not have been working. I should have read more about edit privileges before sharing sandbox.

Comment: Would be great if someone could upvote it. Now that I did freeze the question.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim What duplicate part. I cross-checked for any mistakes and still can't figure? Unless you are intending pun linking to previous question.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52962268/revisions). And on a side note someone added keys to your original sandbox :)

Comment: That I may have done by mistake...after reading your answer. I'll update the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I owe you an apology. This is indeed another reactivity issue which could be solved by providing a [key attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) ..

> The `key` special attribute is primarily used as a hint for Vue’s
> virtual DOM algorithm to identify VNodes when diffing the new list of
> nodes against the old list. Without keys, Vue uses an algorithm that
> minimizes element movement and tries to patch/reuse elements of the
> same type in-place as much as possible. With keys, it will reorder
> elements based on the order change of keys, and elements with keys
> that are no longer present will always be removed/destroyed.

You can assign a unique `key` value to an element, which if changed will force Vue to re-render that element. In your case you can assign keys to your `VCheckbox` elements equal to their `checked` value, forcing Vue to re-render them when they're checked/unchecked. For example ..

```
<HeadItem>
  <VCheckbox
    key={this.allSelected}
    checked={this.allSelected}
    nativeOnChange={e => {
      this.$emit('change', !this.allSelected)
    }}
  />
</HeadItem>
```

I've taken the liberty to re-write your `allSelected` property as a computed property and removed the event listener you set up on the root instance. I think it's much cleaner this way ..

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: You did use computed getter/setter for allSelected. The header checkbox renders as per that computation value passed as prop to Head.vue. Now, when head checkbox fires change event, you have used `$emit` but haven't captured that by say `this.$root.$on('change', ...)` explicitly but by`onChange` function as a prop to `head.vue` component. How does Vuejs handles that internally? I mean in React it was explicit to call `this.props.onChange()` in such a case.

Comment: Second, you have used computed.  Getter of `allSelected` will be fired for every change event of checkbox. Now, what difference `methods{}` could have made if we just had two explicit getAllSelected and setAllSeletected methods ? What benefits in this case would computed offer?

Comment: @kushalvm For some perspective you can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/issues/1802). But basically when a child component uses `$emit`, a parent (the `table` component in your case) can set up a listener on the child instance with `v-on` (`onChange`, `onInput`, `onClick` etc when you use JSX). Any additional arguments you pass when you call `$emit` will be passed to the listener's callback function.

Comment: In your implementation you were using the root instance essentially as an event bus, which isn't idiomatic in Vue. It works fine for your simple case, but the problem is that if the table component gets destroyed the event listener won't be removed unless you specifically call `this.$root.$off('change')`. Contrast this to the other case where [Vue automatically takes care of cleanup for you](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Why-Listeners-in-HTML).

Comment: Also your implementation would cause problems if you had [other components using a 'change' event on the root instance](https://codesandbox.io/s/1v0ynv8q2j). This makes your components unreusable in the same tree and forces you to think about how you name your events so as to not cause a conflict. Contrast this to the case where [everything is nice and localized](https://codesandbox.io/s/vmv50jqwy7).

Comment: RE: computed properties. If we're being scientific you can imagine a situation where you allow a user to change the table's style. In this situation upon re-render a computed property would just use the cached value because you didn't check/uncheck any checkbox, whereas a normal getter method would have to be called for each and every re-render. You could further imagine a situation where you allow the user to drag a mouse on a color-picker and see the table's color change live. In this case, even with throttling, the getter would be called hundreds of times.

Comment: But if we're being practical you won't get any performance improvements from a computed property since you're not doing any of these things and you only have a couple of checkboxes. The only advantage is that with a computed you'll have your property encapsulating its getter and setter so you have everything in one place. With the methods you'd have to initialize your `allSelected` property in the `data` section and have the getter/setter down in the `methods` section.

Comment: Also if you follow the [style-guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-instance-options-order-recommended) your `computed` properties will come right after your `data`, giving you at a glance an idea about your state and what mutations you can have on it.

Comment: All the above has nothing to do with your reactivity issue, which you could solve in your implementation by providing a `key` like I mentioned previously and everything will work fine. It's just that the implementation is unidiomatic/inelegant (opinion, not fact )

Comment: For the computed properties, just wanted to make sure, I didn't miss anything from performance perspective for this case specifically, and turns out there isn't. I do understand the scientific difference :)

Comment: It was good to know the new type of usage and difference for localisation of event. Good solid reference of Github issue. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Everything being clear except for the thing you have mentioned twice that just adding a `key` would solve my issue of reactivity. But I did to my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/0yxyxv5qx0) and no other changes and it didn't work. Am I missing something ?

Comment: [You forgot to add a key to the header checkbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m74vjw19vp).

Comment: Alright @Husam Ibrahim  Nice interacting with you! I surely can't always run bounties :)
I'll love to keep engaged with you somehow esp on Vuejs -  which I recently started digging into - on such small issues and maybe to discuss some deep JS/React fundamentals as well.

Comment: Please let me know if I can reach you out of SO somewhere ( linkedin/facebook/twitter ) or something.